# how to call a dll in python, generated by a Matlab script?

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda, dllimport

I have to load my dll in python 3.6.10 (anaconda) that contains the Matlab script, generated with matlab compiler. I put below a draft of the program, but I do not know if besides the error it gives me, I am wrong to put the path. At the end of the program should start the matlab runtime and give me the graphs as output.

```
import sys
import clr

sys.path.append(r"dll path")
clr.AddReference("dllname")

from dllname import Class
y=Class(r"path of the file that is recalled in matlab on which it has to do the operations)
```

The error that the program gives me is the following:

```
from dllname import Class
ImportError: cannot import name 'Class'
```

Comment: What does your MATLAB script look like?

Comment: my script is a function like this:
function y=dllname (x)
where x is the folder that contains the file that the function must analyze

Comment: Can you share your MATLAB code in your question so we can try and reproduce?

Comment: Why not make the MATLAB script into a stand-alone executable rathe than a DLL? That will be a lot easier to call.

Comment: Hi Cris; could you tell me how I can do it? or if you have an example